# INS-20802 Oracle Services for Microsoft Transaction Server failed (hostname too long)

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I am attempting to install the Oracle Database 19c Client (19.3) for Microsoft Windows (32-bit) - NT_193000_client.zip onto Windows Server 2016 (64-bit) but receive the following error message **[INS-20802] Oracle Services for Microsoft Transaction Server failed**.

The components I have selected during installation was:

- Oracle Net
- Oracle ODBC Driver
- Oracle Provider for OLE DB
- Oracle Data Provider for .NET
- Oracle Providers for ASP.NET

The log file contains the following error:

`INFO: Started Plugin named: Oracle Services For Microsoft Transaction Server
INFO: Found associated job
INFO: Starting 'Oracle Services For Microsoft Transaction Server'
INFO: Starting 'Oracle Services For Microsoft Transaction Server'
INFO: MTSInternalPlugIn: ... adding 
INFO: Not changing the permissions of file C:\Oracle\product\19.0.0\client_1\cfgtoollogs\configTools_2020-08-24_10-27-27AM.log, because current platform is not unix.
INFO: Executing MTS
INFO: Command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c call C:\Oracle\product\19.0.0\client_1\bin\oramtsctl.exe -new -internal
INFO: ... GenericInternalPlugIn.handleProcess() entered.
INFO: ... GenericInternalPlugIn: getting configAssistantParmas.
INFO: ... GenericInternalPlugIn: checking secretArguments.
INFO: No arguments to pass to stdin
INFO: ... GenericInternalPlugIn: starting read loop.
INFO: Service is being created.
INFO: Skipping line: Service is being created.
INFO: End of argument passing to stdin
INFO: Error: hostname servername.subdomain.domain.co.uk is too long.
INFO: Skipping line: Error: hostname servername.subdomain.domain.co.uk is too long.
INFO: Action: specify one IP address of the host when creating the service.
INFO: Skipping line: Action: specify one IP address of the host when creating the service.
INFO: OUI internal: error occurred on localhost
INFO: Skipping line: OUI internal: error occurred on localhost
INFO: Completed Plugin named: Oracle Services For Microsoft Transaction Server
INFO: Setup completed with overall status as Failed`

I am not able to shorten the hostname which is 38 characters long (including subdomain and domain) so is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Did you try to specify the IP address of the host as the message suggests, or, if possible, to specify hostname without domain?

Comment: @gile I am sure you could configure the installation by specifiying the hostname with the just the devicename or using ip but this would have to be done after the failed installation. I have tried installing with a response file and through the wizard neither of which seem to allow you to specify additional installation commands for oramtsctl.exe. This issue never came up when using the 11g or 12c client installation.

Answer (score 0):

This error (hostname too long) does not occur when installing the Oracle 11g or 12c client (perhaps MTS is optional when installing these data providers?).

A workaround is to configure MTS after the installation wizard has failed by using the IP address as the host:

`C:\Oracle\product\19.0.0\client_1\bin>oramtsctl.exe -new -host 192.168.0.10
OracleOraClient19Home1_32bitMTSRecoveryService service is being created.
OracleOraClient19Home1_32bitMTSRecoveryService service was created successfully.
OracleOraClient19Home1_32bitMTSRecoveryService service is starting...
OracleOraClient19Home1_32bitMTSRecoveryService service was started successfully.`